# Trouble in arrow connectionstyle for Astrophysics modelling

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

With this code I am trying to plot this kind of image: [this image is made by powerpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3br.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3br.jpg) but I am unable to get it, I am getting this one: [image: created through code]. Does any one help me in arrow connection style in python. Most important thing that I want to ask, How can I can turn arrow in particular direction and write on them as I have written on image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3br.jpg)

```html
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import fileinput
import os
import shutil
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


start_time = time.time()
colors = ['red','blue','sienna','black', 'orange','olive' , 'green', 'brown',\
 'coral', 'aqua', 'y', 'purple', 'orchid', 'c', 'peru', 'darkcyan',\
 'm', 'darkgoldenrod', 'lime', 'teal', 'indianred', 'lawngreen', 'tan', 'navy', 'pink' ]

#~ electron_density= [1]
hden = [2]
D = [ '15.0','15.50', '16.0',  '16.50',  '17.0',  '17.10',  '17.20',  '17.30',  '17.40', '17.50',\
'17.60',  '17.70',  '17.80',  '17.90', '18.0', '18.10', '18.20', '18.30', '18.40',  '18.50', \
'19.0', '19.50', '20.0', '20.50', '21.0'] #NHI

ionz =  ['-3.4768207','-3.1768207', '-2.9768207', '-2.7768207', '-2.4768207', '-2.1768207', '-1.9768207', '-1.7768207', '-1.4768207'] #ionization parameter U
#~ ionz =  ['-1.4768207']

#~ N = ["z001", "z002", "z003", "z004", "z006", "z008", "z010", "z020"]
#~ N = ["z001", "z002", "z003", "z004", "z006", "z008"]
#~ N = ["z001", "z002", "z003", "z004"]
#~ N = ["z001", "z002"]
N = ["z001"]

#~ age =  ["6.0", "6.3", "6.5", "6.7", "6.9", "7.0", "7.3", "7.5", "7.7", "7.9", "8.0", "8.3", "8.5", "8.7", "8.9" ]
#~ age =  ["7.0", "7.3", "7.5", "7.7", "7.9", "8.0", "8.3", "8.5", "8.7", "8.9" ]
age = ["6.0"]
#~ 
colors = ['red','blue','sienna', 'orange', 'yellow' ,'lime', 'brown',\
 'coral', 'aqua', 'y', 'purple', 'black','orchid', 'olive' ,'c', 'peru', 'darkcyan',\
 'm', 'darkgoldenrod', 'pink',  'teal', 'indianred', 'lawngreen', 'tan', 'navy', 'green' ]
grey = np.linspace(0,1,25)

ratio = [ 'He2Hb_ratio','He2Hb_4686_ratio', 'C4C3_ratio', 'Si4Hb_ratio']
#~ fesc = [99, 99, 98, 95, 86, 83, 80, 75, 70, 63, 56, 48, 40, 31, 24, 18, 13, 9, 7, 4.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
fesc = [99, 99, 98, 95, 86, 83, 80, 75, 70, 63, 56, 48, 40, 31, 24, 18, 13, 9, 7, 4.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

r1 = 3
r2 = 1

#~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Ionization parameter~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
for a in np.arange(len(age)):
 for n in np.arange(len(N)) :
  link = '/home/evol/gsharma/cloudy_work/for_report/final_fig_codes/data/hden_'+str(hden[0])+'/line_ratios/age_'+age[a]+'_'+N[n]+'' #func of NHI_U
  xx = np.transpose(np.loadtxt(''+link+'/'+ratio[r1]+'.txt'))
  yy = np.transpose(np.loadtxt(''+link+'/'+ratio[r2]+'.txt'))
  for m in np.arange(len(ionz)):
   for f in np.arange(len(fesc)):
    if fesc[f]>=1:
     plt.plot(yy[m,f], xx[m,f], 'o-', color= ''+str(grey[f])+'')

    if fesc[f]<1:
     plt.plot(yy[m,f], xx[m,f], 'o-', color= ''+colors[m]+'')


plt.annotate("increasing U",
            xy=(-3.6,-1.1), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-3.7, -2.9), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc"),
            )
              
plt.xlabel('log([SiIV]_1393/H_beta)')
plt.ylabel('log([HeII]_4686/H_beta)')
plt.title('SiIV/Hbeta Vs HeII/Hbeta line ratios \n fesc_U::\ hden_'+str(hden[0])+', fix age , fix Z ')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The annotation parameter takes text at the start of an arrow and points to the feature (this information is in the matplotlib documentation for annotate).

To have the text follow the arrow, you will need to make a separate text box object that is rotated (https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/text_rotation.html). You can still use annotate to create an arrow, but now with an empty string at the beginning.

```
plt.text(-3.8, -1.3, 'Increasing U', rotation = 79)

plt.annotate("",
            xy=(-3.5, -0.9), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-3.8,-3.3), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc"),
            )
```

[Here's a picture of the text and arrow above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gujSm.png)

Note that the rotations begin from horizontal, counterclockwise, measured in degrees - the text rotation link has some nice visual examples.